# Real sequences $\{x_n\} $ and $\{y_n\} $ satisfy $x_n^3-y_n^3\to 0$. When does $x_n-y_n\to0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider two real valued sequences $\{x_n\} $ and $\{y_n\} $ satisfying the condition $x_n^3-y_n^3\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $. Then as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
(A) $x_n - y_n \rightarrow 0$ always
(B) $x_n - y_n \rightarrow 0$ only if $\{x_n\}$ converges.
(C) $x_n - y_n \rightarrow 0$ only if $\{|x_n|-|y_n|\}$ converges.
(D) $x_n - y_n \rightarrow 0$ only if $\{|x_n^2 +x_ny_n+y_n^2|\}$ converges

$\bf{Try:}$
Take $x_n=(-1) ^n$ and $y_n=(-1) ^n+\frac 1n$. Then option(B) is discarded. For the other options I don't have clear idea. But I tried to proceed like this-
Since $x_n^3-y_n^3\rightarrow 0$ hence for some $n>N$ we have $|x_n^3 - y_n^3|<\epsilon \implies |(x_n-y_n) (x_n^2 +x_ny_n+y_n^2) |<\epsilon$
How to conclude?

Comment: It may be surprising, but (A) is the correct answer. – Duplicate Q&A found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_n%5E3-y_n%5E3%5Cto%200%24)